# IllegalStateException in Fragment Transition

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I'm trying to add a new fragment to an empty FrameLayout with a FragmentTransition and I keep getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:2840)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:2735)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:2691)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:2671)
     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:739)
     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:578)
     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1217)
     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:384)
     at android.someApp.OverviewListFragment.showDetailsForSelectedMessage(OverviewListFragment.java:67)
```

When debugging I noticed that the FrameLayout is trying to add itself as its own child, which seems to be causing this exception.

Here is the layout.xml file for the activity that I'm attempting to add the fragment to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment 
        android:name="android.someApp.OverviewListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/overview_list_fragment" 
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="0px" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/scenario_details_container" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is where I'm trying to perform the transition:

```
private void showDetailsForSelectedMessage() {      

    ScenarioDetailsFragment fragment = ScenarioDetailsFragment.newInstance(selectedMessage);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.scenario_details_container, fragment)
        .disallowAddToBackStack() //Problem occurs with and without this line
        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
    .commit();
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}
```

I've beat my head against this problem for too long now.  Does anyone out there have any clue as to whats going on here?

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Did you figured it out? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar exception once and I dont rememebr what and how it was caused. However, try to remove the OverviewListFragment from the xml and change it to a framelayout placeholder. And then create  OverviewListFragment dynamically and add it to the framelayout in onCreate.
Hope this helps.